# Keep Cognito form on every page

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a form that I want to display on every page. That's not a problem. But I want the entered information to be kept when you navigate to another page.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you wanting the information to stay the same even if the user has not submitted the form?  Also, are these pages, pages on your website or pages on a multi-page Cognito form?

Comment: I have one form that i display on every page. Now if someone enters information and goes to another page the entered information is lost. I want that the form keeps the information until you hit the submit button.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While there is not an option in the [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) itself, you can add a bit of script inside your embed code to handle this:

```
<div class="cognito">
    <script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/include/required"></script>
    <script src="https://services.cognitoforms.com/session/script/542df3c7-b22c-43b0-8491-3e0aeab0ce7c"></script>
    <script>
        var entry = localStorage["entry"];
        if (entry)
            entry = JSON.parse(entry);

        Cognito.load("forms", { id: "33", entry: entry });

        $(window).unload(function() { 
            localStorage["entry"] = JSON.stringify(Cognito.serialize(Cognito.Forms.model.entry));
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Here is a link to a Pen showing this working: http://codepen.io/CognitoForms/pen/RNQVBL

You would need to start with the embed code for your form and then replace the final script block using the example above and replace the form number `33` with the number corresponding to your form.  Also, this code assumes you have JQuery included on your page to make it easy to subscribe to the page unload event.

Finally, you will have to decide how to clear this form out, such as adding a bit of code to a page on your site that the page redirects to after it is submitted.  Please give this a try and let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hello thank you for your comment. I don't have the knowledge about coding so i could clean the form. It is ok if it cleans when hit the submit button.

Comment: Start by seeing if you can get this working based on my example above.  One of our developers is working on the easiest way to handle resetting the form once it is submitted successfully.